# Access MSSQL server 2005 over Internet

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting to local Sql server 2005 through Internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/63701/connecting-to-local-sql-server-2005-through-internet)

I want access my local database which is on windows 2003 a local machine.

My website is running on the internet and
I want to access the sql server 2005 Database through the internet, but I am getting the following error. My Firewall is off.

> Error A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server.  The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL 
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond.)

Comment: The connection could be blocked at a few different places.  Does the service hosting the website allow outbound connections on that port?  Do you have a router on your LAN with a built-in firewall?  Also, your ISP could be blocking that port as well.

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions you've already asked.  Edit/comment on the original question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled TCP/IP connections on MSSQL 2005?

May be this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277 will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Umesh's suggestions..... how are you trying to connect to the SQL Server? Do you have a static IP setup for your SQL Server and has that been configured in the SQL Network Configurations Manager?

Answer (score 0):

There is a near 100% possibility that your ISP is blocking port 1433. I would recommend changing the SQL port on the server, and opening it in your firewall, then reconnecting.

Most ISPs will block common ports that are a big target, such as 1433 and Exchange's 143

If you open a command windows and try to telnet to your server on that port, what happens?

Comment: I Changed My Port Address 1433 to 8001,
And Make them in exception in firewall.

And Port 8001 running On Lan Ip Address.
When We connect it with lan ip adn port no it is accessible,
But Through Internet It Gives same error 26.